# Have typescript infer type information from result of function

Tags: typescript, types

Is this possible?

```
type A = {unique_property_to_a: any}
type X = A | B | C;

const isA = (x:X) => !(x instanceof B || x instanceof C)

console.log(isA(x) ? x.unique_property_to_a : null)
```

I can achieve this by inlining the `isA` check - which is what I've been doing so far - but this results in a lot of duplication.

Comment: Yeah it's called a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates). So for your function, it would be `(x: X): x is A => ...` [Example](https://tsplay.dev/wRlJnm)

Comment: that was easy, thanks @kelly

Comment: @kelly why can't typescript infer these type predicates? seems possible